# RegEx acting strange. What am I missing?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm checking for StringPatterns.
This is the RegEx:

```
Regex regEx = new Regex("(\\d{4}/\\d{1})");
```

Text examples look like this: `1234/5,1234/6,1234/8`. Everything works fine till there is a String like "1234/89", and the result of the match is still true. What am I missing? I also had this RegEx:

```
Regex regEx = new Regex("(\\d{4}/\\d{1}\\W)");
```

With the problem, that this one had the examples I mentioned as a non-match and therefor marked them false.

Comment: Why not use /d+ instead of specifically specifying {4} digits and {1} digit.  The last nine of 89 is being dropped because you are only looking for one digit instead of two.

Comment: Tip: Use @ before your string to not have to escape the "\"'s, which makes the entire thing more confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing that fact that your regex should always match the whole string, but in your case, even the part of string is matched. Use start / end anchors:

```
^(\\d{4}/\\d{1})$
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a typical example for not beeing able to see the forest for the trees and embarrassing.

Answer (score -2):

```
static void Code () {

    Regex regEx = new Regex(@"(\d{4}/\d{1,2})");

    foreach (string input in new string [] {
        "1234/5", "1234/6", "1234/8", "1234/89"
    })
        Console.WriteLine (regEx.IsMatch (input));

    /*
        True
        True
        True
        True
    */

}
```

Comment: The last string should return `false`.

Comment: notice the \d{1,2} one or two matches

Comment: Nope - OP's aim is *not* to match `1234/89`.

Comment: The OP's problem is that he wants to allow only patterns like "dddd/d" having exactly 4 digits, a slash and then one digit, but his regex returns `true` even if he has more digits.